# Will the L9823 work at 3.3 V with Wemos boards?

Tags: esp8266, voltage

Or is it 5 V only?

https://www.st.com/en/automotive-analog-and-power/l9823.html

I see in the data sheet it says under Absolute Maximum:

> Supply Voltage:  VDD -0.3 V to 7 V

Then, under Electrical Characteristics:

> 4.5 V < VDD < 5.5 V; unless otherwise specified.

Is the Electrical Characteristics section just listing values for an example voltage of 5 V, or does the chip need 5 V to work properly?

Comment: the datasheet states that the chip may perform an undervoltage reset when supply voltage drops below 3.95 V ... but the undervoltage reset is not not guaranteed until the voltage drops to 2.5 V ... i assume that it is a manufacturing variation .... you would have to screen devices to find one that allows the voltage to drop below 3 V before resetting ... even then, it is unclear if the device would operate at 3.3 V

Answer (score 1):

No. The undervoltage puts it in reset at 3.95V per the ST data sheet. It is a  5v only part with a wide tolerance on VCC. It was designed many years ago as an automotive part. It is a very nice part and performs well.

Answer (score 1):

The *Absolute Maximum* section in a datasheet describes what will damage a component, or shorten its life span; it does not state the acceptable range of values that will make the component work as expected. It is not a design guideline.

You can deduce from these Absolute Maximum data that a V<sub>dd</sub> of 3.3 V will not damage the IC, but not that it will work well at that voltage.

In this case, the datasheet says that all Electrical Characteristics *are specified at* a V<sub>dd</sub> of about 5 V. This by itself does not necessarily mean the IC won't work at lower voltages, but it is a hint.

But, further on in the Electrical Characteristics, it is stated that the IC could reset at any V<sub>dd</sub> between 2.5 V and 3.95 V, so the IC will very probably not work reliably at 3.3V.